# Connecting a laptop to a home theater system sub-woofer

Tags: audio, speakers, home-theater

I have a [Sony DVD Home Theatre System (DAV-DZ340)](http://www.sony.co.in/product/dav-dz340k) and an [Asus U47A laptop](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Superior_Mobility/U47A/). I want my laptop's audio to come out of the 5.1 home theater sound system instead of the laptop speakers. Can I somehow connect the laptop to the sub-woofer or to something else in a way in which it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug a suitable lead from the **line-out** socket of your laptop to the **line-in** socket of the amplifier unit of the DAV-DZ340.

[image]

From [Manual](http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/4286726111.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cable like this. PLug into your earphone jack on laptop and the RCA should go into AUX, Line IN on your Home Audio System.

[image]

Sometimes your Home Audio System also uses a Jack as an Input so use this cable instead.

[image]

By the looks of your Audio system ...

[image]

.. you will need the RCA plugs put into the TV/AV (cant read it to well) input. Then set it to TV so that it can play audio from your notebook.

TIPS

- Do not put you notebook on 100% volume. Try and keep it below 90% and pump up the volume on the amplifier system. Also do not overcrank the equalizer on the notebook. Use the amplifier to it. It will do a much better job!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get 5.1 audio out of that laptop is, as far as I'm aware, through the HDMI out. Try connecting it to the amplifier with an HDMI cable.

Comment: Actually, from your link it doesn't appear your amplifier has HDMI input. If this is the case, sorry for misleading you.